# Javascript setTimeout(); for ProgressBar doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css

On my website I have a progressbar and when I click the *Download* button, the progressbar starts. By the way I want it to progress a bit slowly, so I thought I could use `setTimeout();`.

http://jsfiddle.net/pHxSy/9/

If you look at that jsfiddle, when you click the *Download* button anything happens. I've tested it on firefox and the console tells me `ReferenceError: startTime is not defined`.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Don't just link to a fiddle, put the relevant code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have some errors in the fiddle you shared

1. `onclick="startTime(i);"`should be  `onclick="startTime(0)"`
2. the line

   ```
   document.getElementById("movingbar").style.width = i + "%";
   ```

should be

```
   document.getElementById("prog").style.width = i + "%";
```

as you div name is `prog` instead of `movingbar`

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mithunsatheesh/pHxSy/13/)

Answer (score 1):

set your `onclick="startTime(i);"`
 as `onclick="startTime(0);"`

```
<input value="Download" type="button" onclick="startTime(0);">
```

Here is [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/utUqIdA/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

set value in the function parm

```
<input value="Download" type="button" onclick="startTime(0);">
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pHxSy/10/)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path, only few fixes are necessary:

- `onclick="startTime(i);"` should be `onclick="startTime(0);"`
- `.getElementById("movingbar")` should be `.getElementById("prog")`
- `setTimeout('startTime('+i+')',50);` should be `setTimeout(function(){ startTime(i); }, 50);`.

The latter point is usually a best practise. You don't want to trigger `eval` in Javascript (have a look [here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)).

The working js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wkbj4/).

Lastly, if you want to make it progress slower as you reach the end, you could use a simple trick:

```
setTimeout(function(){ startTime(i); }, 50 + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find working fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/BWamw/

or just paste this code no need to pass argument when calling startTime()

```
var progress = 0;
var interval;
function startTime() {
    interval = window.setInterval(function () {
       document.getElementById("prog").style.width = progress + "%";
       progress++;
       if (progress >= 100) {
           interval =window.clearInterval(interval)
       }
    }, 100)
}
```

you should better you setInterval 
it will execute specified function at some interval of time.
by this you can avoid recursion

it is also simple to use.